# How to set default access to field.camelcase-underscore using Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-configuration

would like to set this convention up globally if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a [convention](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Conventions), of which there are some [shortcuts](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Convention_shortcut) for the common scenarios. Specifically, there's a `DefaultAccess` shortcut, with a `CamelCaseField(prefix)` method.

```
.Conventions.Add(
  DefaultAccess.CamelCaseField(CamelCasePrefix.Underscore)
);
```